# Connect MQTTBox with RabbitMQ Server for load testing

Tags: testing, rabbitmq, load, mqtt

I was trying to connect mqttbox(Chrome extension) to rabbitmq server for load testing. The client created in mqqtbox is connecting properly but its not able to do load testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No much to change, just enable the guest user with administrator permission will resolve the issue.